# Importing a file local to an npm module

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I have a node module named redux-loop that I'm using, and I would like to modify one of its functions slightly.

It's not a [very complicated file](https://github.com/raisemarketplace/redux-loop/commit/1c8e00954847e089dc71c8c317b312f1b8e348ef), so I've made a copy of it in my react-native app and made my changes.  The original code requires a few exports from files inside the module, eg:

```
var { loop, isLoop, getEffect, getModel } = require('./loop');
var { batch, none } = require('./effects');
```

The problem is that my copy of this file cannot seem to get direct access to those files, so I can't import those symbols.

I've tried various combinations of things, such as:

```
var { loop, isLoop, getEffect, getModel } = require('redux-loop/loop');
var { batch, none } = require('redux-loop/effects');
```

…which conceptually would mean to me to require the `loop.js` file inside the `redux-loop` module, but apparently module loading doesn't work that way.

What's the best way for me to import theses symbols into this file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and you're open to reapplying your changes to the source of the package, you could use [`npm edit <pkg>`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/edit) and modify the package directly. When your changes are done the package will be rebuilt with your modifications.